# How to save a tree like form in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ancestry

I want to build a dynamic form where you can add textboxes and child textboxes and so on... like a tree, all this data should be saved in the same table with a parent_id field.

What do you guys think is the best approach to accomplish this in Rails?

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: I would be more likely to do this in javascript using jQuery to make life easier

Comment: Yes, the adding textbox part to the view is easy, the question is how do you process the post in the controller to save the parent_id relationship?